# How can I rotate the bounding boxes from findcontours function in Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, mnist

I have the following image:

[image]

I am using OpenCV to find the contours in this image in order to separate the "122" into "1","2", and "2". I am using OCR to classify the numbers after.
The code I am using to do this is as follows:

```
invert = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(invert, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
# perform edge detection, find contours in the edge map, and sort the
# resulting contours from left-to-right
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 30, 150)
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")[0]

# initialize the list of contour bounding boxes and associated
# characters that we'll be OCR'ing
chars = []
preds = []
for c in cnts:
    # compute the bounding box of the contour
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # filter out bounding boxes, ensuring they are neither too small
    # nor too large
    if (w >= 5 and w <= 150) and (h >= 15 and h <= 120):
        # extract the character and threshold it to make the character
        # appear as *white* (foreground) on a *black* background, then
        # grab the width and height of the thresholded image
        roi = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        thresh = cv2.threshold(roi, 0, 255,
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        (tH, tW) = thresh.shape

        # if the width is greater than the height, resize along the
        # width dimension
        if tW > tH:
            thresh = imutils.resize(thresh, width=32)
        # otherwise, resize along the height
        else:
            thresh = imutils.resize(thresh, height=32)

        # re-grab the image dimensions (now that its been resized)
        # and then determine how much we need to pad the width and
        # height such that our image will be 32x32
        (tH, tW) = thresh.shape
        dX = int(max(0, 32 - tW) / 2.0)
        dY = int(max(0, 32 - tH) / 2.0)

        # pad the image and force 32x32 dimensions
        padded = cv2.copyMakeBorder(thresh, top=dY, bottom=dY,
            left=dX, right=dX, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
            value=(0, 0, 0))
        padded = cv2.resize(padded, (28, 28))

        # prepare the padded image for classification via our
        # handwriting OCR model
        padded = padded.astype("float32") / 255.0
        padded = np.expand_dims(padded, axis=-1)

        # update our list of characters that will be OCR'd
        chars.append((padded, (x, y, w, h)))
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        roi=image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        plt.imshow(roi)
```

This code works great for numbers that are not written at an angle and are spaced generously apart, however in this image we see that the "1" is angled slightly. The resulting bounding box around the one also includes a portion of the adjacent "2".

[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can slightly rotate the bounding box to exclude the portion of the two?

Comment: [`minAreaRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d62/tutorial_bounding_rotated_ellipses.html) should get you what you need.

Comment: I suggest reading the entirety of the [OpenCV-Python Tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html). It will give you the foundation for all of these simple types of use-cases. For this specific one, [Contour Features](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) should help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give specific recommendations without understanding how the bounding box will be used downstream.

Easiest method would be to use the [boxPoints](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf78d467e024b4d7936cf9397185d2f5c) function. That will return the coordinates of the corners for the minimum bounding box around the contour. Alternatively, you could [fit a line](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf849da1fdafa67ee84b1e9a23b93f91f) to the contour and use the angle of the line to rotate your your bounding box.